# Array element is "9" when printed but not equals 9 in a comparison (==)

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, equals

the code tells if the sum of every other element in an array of int (input 2) is equal to target (input 3).

```
public static boolean groupNoAdj(int start, int[] nums, int target) {
  if (nums.length<=2){
    System.out.println(nums[0]+""+target);
    return (nums[0]==target);
  }
  int hey = nums[start];
  int[] bleb = Arrays.copyOfRange(nums, start+2, nums.length);
  bleb[0] += hey;
  groupNoAdj(0, bleb, target);
  return false; // doesn't ever run
}
```

However, this only seems to work with an array with 1 element.

- `groupNoAdj(0, {9}, 9)` returns true, as intended.
- `groupNoAdj(0, {3, 3294582, 6}, 9)` returns false.

I added a print to print the values of both variables on line 3 `System.out.println(nums[0]+""+target);` which prints 99 (9 = num[0], 9 = target). `nums[0]==target`, then, should be `true`.

But `groupNoAdj(0, {3, 3294582, 6}, 9)` returns false, despite being 9. When either of the prompts of `nums[0]==target` is replaced with 9, `false` is also returned, despite the print code showing that both are 9.

Comment: why did you write that `return false; // doesn't ever run`  never runs?? If `nums.length` is greater than 2 it will definitively run (unless some previous statement throws an Exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning from the recursive call at the end of the method.  Replace

```
groupNoAdj(0, bleb, target);
return false; // doesn't ever run
```

with

```
 return groupNoAdj(0, bleb, target);
```